# How to avoid the API level check on XML files?

Tags: android

I want to add the card flip animation shown by google in [their documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) between two activities. My project targets the API Level 10 so I can't even add their xml animation files to my projects `res/anim` folder because `android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"` isn't supported in my project target API Level.

I wouldn't mind if this visual enhancement only works in the devices that support the animation. How can I use this animation only the devices that support the animation if I can't even add the animation file as it won't compile because of the API Level check.

Comment: you'd have to target a higher api, declare backward compatibility with api10, and put 2 different animation using resource selectors folders.

Comment: @njzk2 could you explain how to declare backward compatibility and how would the folder structure be so I can have multiple animation files one for API level 10 and the other for API level 11 and above?

Answer (score 0):

You can, probably, copy accelerate_decelerate.xml from sdk/platform/... to your project and then use it if your API level allows that.